# PHP Script - Sending data ($_POST) for then will be able to parsing data

Tags: php, forms, post

I have searching but without success :/

Sorry if it's something duplicated, but with my searches I couldn't find something similar with this.

I'm trying to make a script, to a non API webservice, for we can be able to tracking packages.

The website has this form:

```
<form id="objectSearch" name="objectSearch" action="/feapl_2/app/open/objectSearch/cttObjectSearch.jspx" method="post" class="objSearch">

<input type="hidden" name="objects" value="" id="objectSearch_objects">
<input type="hidden" name="showResults" value="true" id="objectSearch_showResults">
<fieldset>
    <textarea name="pesqObjecto.objectoId" cols="40" rows="4" id="objectSearch_pesqObjecto_objectoId" class="sizeBig" title="pesqObjecto.objectoId"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="PESQUISAR" onclick="var b=validationForm();return b;" align="right" id="objectSearchSend" class="CPFormSubmit1">

    <input type="reset" value="LIMPAR" align="left" class="CPFormSubmit1">
</fieldset>
```

How can I send the required form fields with PHP? With cURL? If yes, how can I pass this form field name 'pesqObjecto.objectoId' with that '.' in PHP ?

Edit: If it helps, this is the page i try to get the info:
      http://www.ctt.pt/feapl_2/app/open/tools.jspx?tool=0

Then I think I wont't have problems, parsing website, but if you have some advices that's better for this stuff I will be appreciated :)

Thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm very not sure, but try to do something like that

```
<?php   

    $timeout = 10;
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>';
    $lien="http://www.ctt.pt/feapl_2/app/open/objectSearch/cttObjectSearch.jspx?"; 
    $curl = curl_init($lien);
    $postfields=array('objects'=>'','showResults'=>true,'pesqObjecto.objectoId'=>'LX123456789PT');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    $contenu_page = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    echo $contenu_page;
    echo '<script>$(function(){$("#objectSearch").attr("action","'.$lien.'");$("#objectSearchSend").click();});</script>';
```

Comment: Hello, 
thanks for your answer. I've done something similar with what you gave me and the result are the same, it returns all page with the form, but the form it's already with the pesqObjecto.objectoId filled.
If it helps, this is the page:
http://www.ctt.pt/feapl_2/app/open/tools.jspx?tool=0

thanks for your help.

Comment: I modified my answer. check it

Comment: I get it what are you doing but still not working here. 
Just happen the same, return the page with search field filled :(

Comment: sorry put the correct src for include jquery file.
you see echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>';  
... replace them by:
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="your_jquery_file"></script>';

Comment: Also i'm a frenchie, sorry for my bad english :p

Comment: Hi, don't sorry, I'm sorry, didn't see that problem :S
I saw you have jquery but thought it was by CDN, my bad.
It's working great, very very thanks for that sir!
I'm portuguese, and my english it's not so good to :)

Thank you again!